# Local extremes of $f(x) = (x-2)^{\frac{1}{5}}(x-7)^{\frac{1}{9}}$

Tags: analysis, derivatives

The task is to find local extremes of $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $f(x) = (x-2)^{\frac{1}{5}}(x-7)^{\frac{1}{9}}$

There is theorem that if $x_{0}$ is local extreme of $f(x)$ then $f'(x_0) = 0$

So I start from calculating derivative of $f(x)$
$$f'(x) = ((x-2)^{\frac{1}{5}}(x-7)^{\frac{1}{9}})' = \frac19(x-7)^{-\frac{8}{9}}(x-2)^\frac15 + \frac15(x-2)^{-\frac45}(x-7)^\frac19 = \\ = (x-2)^\frac15(x-7)^\frac19\cdot[\frac19(x-7)^{-1}+\frac15(x-2)^{-1}] = \\ = (x-2)^\frac15(x-7)^\frac19\cdot[\frac{14x-73}{(9x-63)(5x-10)}]= (*)$$

So $(*) = 0 <=> x = 2 \lor x = 7 \lor x = \frac{73}{14}$

How can I check if any of them is local extreme?
(according to wolframalpha $\frac{73}{14}$ is local minimum and there is no local maximum)

Comment: There are some issues since $f(x)=x^{1/5}$ and $g(x)=x^{1/9}$ are usually defined only over $x\geq 0$. Besides that, since your function is a product, it is more effective to study its logarithm (or minus its logarithm) to find stationary points.

Answer (score 1):

for $$f'(x)$$ i have got $$f'(x)=1/45\,{\frac {14\,x-73}{ \left( x-2 \right) ^{4/5}} \left( x-7
 \right) ^{-{\frac {8}{9}}}}
$$ and for the second derivative we have
$$f''(x)=-{\frac {434\,{x}^{2}-4526\,x+15416}{2025\, \left( x-2 \right) ^{9/5}}
 \left( x-7 \right) ^{-{\frac {17}{9}}}}
$$ here you must plugg in $$x_0=\frac{73}{14}$$

Comment: Ok, so I can show that $x_0 = \frac{73}{14}$ is local minimum by showing that $ f''(\frac{73}{14}) < 0$.

But how can I prove that  $x_0 = 2$ and  $x_0 = 7$ are not local extremes?

Comment: it is a local maximum if $$f''(\frac{73}{14})<0$$ look what the first derivative do at the points $x=2$ or $x=7$

Comment: i think your $f'(x)$ is not true

Comment: According to wolfram alpha it is correct. 

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x-2%29%5E%281%2F5%29%28x-7%29%5E%281%2F9%29%29%27+%3D+%28x-2%29%5E%281%2F5%29%28x-7%29%5E%281%2F9%29%28%2814x-73%29%2F%28%289x-63%29%285x-10%29%29%29&a=%5E_Real

Comment: thank you for your downvoting

Comment: Mine? I do not have 125 reputation, so I cannot down vote.